# C# GUI question

Tags: c#, interface, skin, appearance

Does someone know some good `C#` GUI libraries *(opensource / commercial).*

I want to develop my own graphics user interface, probably something `Acronis`-like.

*Skin support is welcome, but not necessary.*

Thank you.

Comment: Given the normal meaning of the word "interface" in C#, you may want to edit your question (and particularly your title) to make it clear that you're talking about *user* interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably look into using WPF, which is built into .NET. It is an extremely extensible, flexible, and powerful UI platform that should give you more than enough flexibility to create an Acronis like UI (I assume you mean Acronis the company that makes backup software.)

Here are some useful links on WPF:

- [Windows Presentation Foundation (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation)
- [Windows Client Network](http://windowsclient.net/)
- [Windows Presentation Foundation (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx)